# In MySQL, issues with using GROUP BY and HAVING to SELECT information from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, having

Find the names of all skills that are **possessed by at least one applicant** or are **needed for at least one position**. Do not list the identical names many times.

```
CREATE TABLE SPOSSESSED(
anumber     DECIMAL(6)  NOT NULL, /*applicant*/   
sname       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    /*skill name*/      
slevel      DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE SNEEDED(
pnumber DECIMAL(8)  NOT NULL,    /*position*/    
sname   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, /*skill name*/
slevel  DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL);
```

If it's getting individually for each table, I've come out with

```
SELECT sname FROM SPOSSESSED GROUP BY sname HAVING COUNT(anumber) >= 1;
SELECT sname FROM SNEEDED GROUP BY sname HAVING COUNT (pnumber) >= 1;
```

The issue I am having is combining this two WITHOUT JOIN/UNION. There is a method that I have tried:

```
SELECT SPOSSESSED.sname FROM SPOSSESSED, SNEEDED
WHERE SPOSSESSED.sname = SNEEDED.sname
GROUP BY SPOSSESSED.sname
HAVING COUNT (pnumber) >= 1 
OR COUNT (anumber) >= 1;
```

However, the result does not equal to the individual SELECT statements.

Comment: Your question doesn't makes sense.  First, `,` is just an old fashioned way of doing joins -- and you should never use it.  Second, you need a join or union or equivalent construct to bring data together from multiple tables.  That is how SQL works.

Comment: Your attempt actually _does_ do a join; it does a pre ANSI-92 implicit join, which is generally considered to be bad syntax.  Really, the only way to do what you want here is to do a join or maybe a union.

Comment: Right, I guess the only way to to UNION those 2 SELECT statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense.  Even worse, it seems to push the use of commas for expressing joins -- something so old fashioned that it makes me think of women being encouraged to smoke or adding lead to gasoline.

Here is one way to do what you want in MySQL:

```
create temporary table t as 
    SELECT sname FROM SPOSSESSED GROUP BY sname HAVING COUNT(anumber) >= 1;

insert into t (sname)
    SELECT sname FROM SNEEDED GROUP BY sname HAVING COUNT(pnumber) >= 1;

select distinct sname
from t;
```

I should note that the `having` condition is irrelevant.  The numbers you are referring to are never `NULL`.  I left it in because it is part of your original queries.

Possibly the most reasonable way to answer this question uses neither explicit `join` nor `union`.  It does assume a "skills" table, however:

```
select s.*
from skills s
where exists (select 1 from spossessed p where p.sname = s.sname) or
      exists (select 1 from sneeded n where n.sname = s.sname);
```